# Could not able to pass parameters

Tags: csv, selenium, webdriver, jmeter

```
 var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
    var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
    var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
  WDS.browser.get('https://example.com')
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,15000) 
var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login_txtUserName')).sendKeys(['sample'])
//userName.click()
//userName.sendKeys(['pandian'])
var userPwd = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login_txtPassword')).sendKeys(['1234'])
//userPwd.click()
//userPwd.sendKeys(['1234'])
var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login_btnLogin')).click()
//button.click()
```

![In the Username:'Sample' & Password: '1234' i want to parameterize with list of values i have in csv][1]

If i try to parameterize with CSV config and if i use ${username} in my sendkeys...it doesn't execute. kindly provide some details for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `Parameters` section at the top of "Script" input field.

You can pass your `${username}` and `${password}` in Parameters stanza you'll be able to refer it as `WDS.args[0]` and `WDS.args[1]` correspondingly

Something like:

```
var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login_txtUserName')).sendKeys([WDS.args[0]])
var userPwd = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login_txtPassword')).sendKeys([WDS.args[1])
```

Should work.

You can test it as follows:

Assuming that you provide the following line as "Parameters"

```
Sample 1234
```

And having the following lines in "Script"

```
WDS.log.info('Parameter 1:'+ WDS.args[0])
WDS.log.info('Parameter 2:' + WDS.args[1])
```

You'll see something like:

```
2014/06/24 15:57:16 INFO  - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: Parameter 1:Sample 
2014/06/24 15:57:16 INFO  - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: Parameter 2:1234
```

in *jmeter.log* file (usually lives in /bin folder of JMeter installation)

See [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) guide for more details.

Comment: Can I pass in the webdriver parameters: ${username} ${password} where those values are read from a CSV file?

Comment: @OphirPrusak Yes you can. the UN & Pwd will take the values from the csv you specified in CSV config...